# ZK Intercept button click from parent window

Tags: zk

I have this zul:

```
<zk>
<style>
    tr.z-listitem-seld { background-image:none ; background-color :
    LIGHTSKYBLUE;}
</style>
<window self="@define(content)" id="winReportFatturePassive" apply="controller.ReportFatturePassive">
    <div align="center">
        <panel sclass="grid_report_log">
            <panelchildren>
                ..........
                ..........
                ..........
                ..........                                      
                <!-- Dettagli POD -->
                <window id="winDettagliPod" visible="false">    
                    <separator spacing="30px" />    
                    <grid oddRowSclass="none" >
                        <columns>
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                            <column align="center" hflex="1" />
                        </columns>
                        <rows>
                            <row valign="top" style="background:#FFFFFF;">
                                <label value="${labels.app.Pod}" />                                             
                            </row>
                            <row>
                                <textbox id="txtPodDettagliPod" width="120px" />    
                                <button id="btnFilterTechDettagliPod" label="${labels.app.filter}" />                                                                                       
                            </row>
                        </rows>
                    </grid>
                    ..........
                    ..........      
                    ..........
                    ..........                          
                </window>                               
            </panelchildren>
        </panel>
    </div>
</window>
```

How is possibile itercept click on button btnFilterTechDettagliPod in sub-window winDettagliPod in controller ReportFatturePassive ?

My Controller Java is:

```
public class ReportFatturePassive extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
```

Is possibile use a simil code:

```
@Listen(Events.ON_CLICK + " = #btnFilterTechDettagliPod")
```

public void FilterTechDettagliPod() throws Exception {
}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of use, I think you should try the Event Queues.
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues#Subscribe_to_an_Event_Queue

This first article is working in MVC.

In this second one you will find an exemple with MVVM.
It's a shopping cart example. I think this is close to your need. When you add an article to the shopping cart, you have to force refresh of an other windows.
http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/advanced/communication_between_viewmodel_and_composer.html